# get file from POST request using javax library

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I am trying to connect AWS SDK to the project, written in JAVA EE.
I have written a service, which interacts with aws server. I am able to create, delete, upload buckets/files. Once I am sending a file directly from file system everything is great.

In other class I am trying to receive file from POST method from page like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


    <input type="file" onchange="handler(this.files[0])" />


    <script type="text/javascript">

        const handler = (file) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(file.name, file);

            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'form/multipart'
                },
                body: formData
            };

            // Здесь ссылку на команду
            fetch(`http://localhost:8800/files/setVideo`, requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        };

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and my controller method looks like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("files")
public class FilesWork{
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
@POST
    @Path(value = "/setVideo")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String UploadFileToCloud( what to write here? ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ServletException {
        String tempFilePath = "/tempFiles";                                     //dir for temp files
        String fileName = "temp";                                               //file name to create temp file
        
        File FileExt = new File(tempFilePath, fileName);                        //create empty file    
        
        fileName = FunctionsGlobal.extractFileName(part);                       //get real file name
        InputStream IOFile = part.getInputStream();                             //get steam from part
        
        Files.copy(IOFile, FileExt.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); //rewrite temp file with real from stream
                        
        AWSUtils s3 = new AWSUtils();
       
        JsonObject UrlBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("Link", "some").build();

        return FunctionsGlobal.returnDataAll(UrlBuilder);

    }
    

}
```

I've tried to use javax.servlet.http.Part to get file, but HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type is thrown from server.

If I try to write it like:

```
public String UploadFileToCloud(File file){}
```

then I actually have a file, but it looks like rep7876328953083992008tmp and I do not know how to change it to normal form.

So, main question is how correctly get file from POST request formed in 'form/multipart' using javax library.

Thanks everyone in advance and have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution to deal with files were found [here](https://nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/jason_lee1/2014/05/file_uploads_with_jax_rs_2). This is custom MultipartRequestMap implementation which I use to get file and/or flags from multipart/form-data request